# Error while updating property 'borderStyle' of a view managed by: RCTView

Tags: android, css, expo

I have this error while I'm testing my app in the android emulator. Someone knows what happens here and how can I resolve? Thanks.

Expo version 41.0.0

[image: Error]

Comment: see supported border styles: https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#borderstyle - notice that 'hidden' is not a valid value

Comment: @brentvatne thank you so much for your help, now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error. In my case it was due to value of some border properties written as a string.
Change:

```
borderWidth: '1px'
borderRadius: '50%'
```

to

```
borderWidth: 1
borderRadius: 50
```

Etc.

Comment: This solution worked for me. It seems that React Native does not support string values for border-radius.